# Making a method available within a block without changing its context?

Tags: ruby

I would like to create a class that does the following:

- Its instance accepts a block.
- During instance initialization, it executes certain actions, then calls the block, then executes more actions.
- Within the block, another method from that class should be available.

Here is how i want it to work:

```rb
Foo.new do
  puts "Hell, I can get you a toe by 3 o'clock this afternoon..."
  bar
  puts "...with nail polish."
end
```

I have managed to achieve it with the following class:

```rb
class Foo

  def initialize(&block)

    puts "This represents a beginning action"

    instance_eval &block

    puts "This symbolizes an ending action"

  end

  def bar
    puts "I should be available within the block."
  end

end
```

As you see, i use the `instance_eval` trick. It enables using `bar` within the block.

It works fine, but the problem here is that `instance_eval` makes current local context unavailable. If i use it from within another class, i lose access to that class' methods. For example:

```rb
class Baz
  def initialize
    Foo.new do
      bar  # -> Works
      quux # -> Fails with "no such method"
    end
  end

  def quux
    puts "Quux"
  end
end
```

The question is: how do i allow executing `bar` within the block without losing access to `quux`?

The only way that comes to my newbie mind is passing `bar` as an argument into the block. But that requires more typing, so i would like to aviod that if possible.

Comment: Upvote for The Big Lebowski reference... Nicely done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instance_eval` does not consider the scope of where the block is called, so every method call is only relative to what is defined inside Foo.

So you have 2 options. Either

```
def initialize
  baz = self
  Foo.new do
    bar  # -> Works
    baz.quux # -> Works
  end
end
```

or

```
def initialize
  puts "This represents a beginning action"
  yield self
  puts "This symbolizes an ending action"
end

....

def initialize
  Foo.new do |b|
    b.bar  # -> Works too
    quux # -> Works too
  end
end
```

I am not sure which one would be better performance wise, but the option you pick is based on your own preference.

Comment: Good, concise explanation.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Steven. With the first approach, my problem is this: https://gist.github.com/lolmaus/d5ae61584479e97aac16 The second approach does work!

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov The reason why you can't call bar inside the quux method is because you have already called quux from the Baz object, which means that `self` is no longer Foo. Your solution to that is by passing Foo as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> It works fine, but the problem here is that instance_eval makes
>   current local context unavailable

instance_eval() does no such thing.  The code inside *all* blocks, i.e something that looks like:

```
{ code here }
```

can see the variables that existed in the surrounding scope at the time the block was CREATED.  A block cannot see the variables in the surrounding scope at the time the block is EXECUTED.  In computer science jargon, a block is known as a *closure* because it 'closes over' the variables in the surrounding scope at the time it is created.

What instance_eval *does do* is assign a new value to the self variable that the block closed over.  Here is an example:

```
puts self  #=>main
func = Proc.new {puts self}  
func.call  #=>main

class Dog
  def do_stuff(f)
    puts self
    f.call
  end
end

d = Dog.new
d.do_stuff(func) 

--output:--
#<Dog:0x000001019325b8>
main   #The block still sees self=main because self was equal to main when the block was created and nothing changed the value of that self variable
```

Now with instance_eval:

```
class Dog
  def do_stuff(f)
    puts self
    instance_eval &f
  end
end

d = Dog.new
d.do_stuff(func) 

--output:--
#<Dog:0x000001011425b0>
#<Dog:0x000001011425b0>  #instance_eval() changed the value of a variable called self that the block `closed over` at the time the block was created
```

You also need to realize that when you call a method and you don't specify a 'receiver', e.g.

```
quux()
```

...then ruby converts that line to:

```
self.quux()
```

So, it is important to know the value of the variable self.  Examine this code:

```
class Dog
  def do_stuff(f)
    puts self  #Dog_instance
    instance_eval &f  #equivalent to self.instance_val &f, 
                      #which is equivalent to Dog_instance.instance_eval &f
  end
end
```

Because instance_eval() sets the value of the self variable inside the block to instance_eval()'s 'receiver', the value of self inside the block is set equal to a Dog_instance.

Examine your code here:

```
puts self #=> main

Foo.new do
  puts self  #=>main

  bar  #equivalent to self.bar--and self is not a Foo or Baz instance
       #so self cannot call methods in those classes  
end
```

Examine your code here:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval &block  #equivalent to self.instance_eval &block
  end
end
```

And inside Foo#initialize() self is equal to the new Foo instance.  That means inside the block self is set equal to a Foo instance, and therefore if you write the following inside the block:

```
quux()
```

That is equivalent to:

```
self.quux()
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Foo_instance.quux()
```

which means quux() must be defined in Foo.

In this answer:

```
class Baz
  def initialize
    puts self  #=>Baz_instance

    baz = self

    Foo.new do
      bar  # -> Works
      baz.quux # -> Works
    end

  end

  def quux
    puts "Quux"
  end
end

b = Baz.new
```

...the bar and baz lines seem to have identical 'receivers':

```
   puts self  #=>Baz_instance

   baz = self  #To evaluate that assignment ruby has to replace the variable self 
               #with its current value, so this is equivalent to baz = Baz_instance
               #and baz no longer has any connection to a variable called self.

   Foo.new do
      bar  #=> equivalent to self.bar, which is equivalent to Baz_instance.bar
      baz.quux  #=> equivalent to Baz_instance.quux
    end
```

But when instance_eval() executes that block, which is everything between the do and end, instance_eval() changes the value of self:

```
   Foo.new do #instance_eval changes self inside the block so that self = Foo_instance
      bar  #=> equivalent to self.bar which is now equivalent to Foo_instance.bar
      baz.quux  #=> the block still sees baz = Baz_instance, so equivalent to Baz_instance.bar
    end
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, 7stud. (nevermind, was wrong here)

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov, That code does not produce the error you say it does; it produces the error: `in 'initialize': uninitialized constant Baz::Foo (NameError)`

Comment: @7stud, did you try to run it? It's a snippet, not fully functional code. I tried your approach on my project and failed. To explain the issue, i took your snippet (third from the end) and modified it to correspond to what i'm doing in my project.